# How can I set maxIdleTimeMS by command line or mongo-shell?

Tags: php, mongodb, database-administration

I have deployed my PHP application (Just out of curiosity, we're using Laravel) and we're using MongoDB in the persistence layer. However , I've noticed a high connection number in connection pool.
It strikes me that connections remain opened for many minutes before it be closed.
The [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) parameter seems like what I looking for (even though I'm not sure...).

That said, I would like to know how could I to set the [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) parameter through MongoDB Shell or command line (or even via configuration file). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

> Please, see the important note on below [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201318/how-can-i-set-maxidletimems-by-command-line-or-mongo-shell#comment65255826_36201318) from **@jmikola**

Comment: It is a connection option, so no way to change it thru shell. Did you try to set it as an `option` in [laravel config](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#configuration) ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Technically it's just part of the URI, so there is nothing stopping you from doing `mongo mongodb://localhost/test?maxIdleTimeMS=30000`, but not that it will actually do anything in this case if the application itself does not apply the option on connection. But as for the OP's question the reason why connections stay open is because if you used that many then it seems reasonable that you are going to use them again. You should only need to "tune" this if your application is very "bursty" in the connections usage.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for reply! I have suspected it too. Think it's only possible in URI connection options.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks so much for additional information.

Comment: You guys are right. Here is another link regarding this topic: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133231/how-can-i-set-maxidletimems-by-command-line-or-mongo-shell

Comment: On a tangential note, neither the old (`ext-mongo`) nor new (`ext-mongodb`) PHP driver uses a connection pool, so the `maxIdleTimeMS` option is ignored. libmongoc, which is used by the new driver and happens to support connection pools for multi-threaded applications (PHP does not use that mode) also does not support the `maxIdleTimeMS` option at all (see: [CDRIVER-278](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-278)).

Comment: @jmikola Thank you so much for this useful notes. I didn't know that. As you are the main maintainer of PHP Mongodb Client that info  it's so helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen  immortal method https://www.php.net/manual/de/mongocursor.immortal.php , is it related somehow to this?